# Ignoring Hidden Files git

Tags: git

I added files ending with `~` in my repository in GitHub and now I want to remove them.

For example I added:

```
README.md
```

and the file

```
README.md~
```

was added as well.

Any help please?

Comment: So what do you want exactly? To remove them (`git rm`), to prevent them from being added again (`man gitignore`), or to rewrite your history so they appear to have never been added?

Comment: rewrite history so they appear to have never been added and removed them from current repository!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For ignoring all the file ending with a `~` you should add this to the `.gitignore` file at the top-level in your repository (alongside the `.git` directory).

```
# Ignore all emacs backup files
*~
```

Then, for changing the history and removing the `README.md~` file, you can either do it manually with `git rebase --interactive` or try to use `git filter-branch`:

```
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch README.md~' HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I run git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch README.md~' HEAD after putting .gitignore. That fixed everything!

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to ignore these files you don't wish to appear in your repository.

To remove the files, you can use

```
git rm README.md~
```

then commit as usual.

Comment: Is there a way to remove all files ending with *~ . And how can I add this to .gitignore ? Thanks

Comment: You could try something like:

`git rm *~`

Then add to your .gitignore file:

`*~`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the history, the easiest way is probably to use `git rebase -i`:

1. remove the file with `git rm`, add `*~` to your .gitignore, and commit your changes
2. `git rebase -i commit_before_the_file_was_added`
3. in your text editor, put the line of your last commit just after the one of the commit in which you added the file, and change "pick" to "fixup"
4. save, exit, watch magic happen
5. double-check that your history is fine, and `git push -f`.

...or you can use what's suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932622/git-erase-files-from-repository-from-previous-commits).